# Como efetuar o @Override de uma function em AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Eu tenho um controller abstrato com o angularjs.

Nele tenho dentre outras coisas, uma toolbar de pesquisa.

Gostaria de usar esse input de pesquisa em todos os controllers que herdem do controller pai. sendo acionados através de um "ng-change".

```
function IndexCtrl() {
  var vm = this;
  //Objects
  vm.searchText = '';

  //Methods
  vm.search = search;

  function search(search) {

  }
}

function TesteCtrl() {
    var vm = this;

    //Methods
    vm.search = search;

    function search(search) {
      console.log(search);
    }
}
```

Quais alternativas de implementação eu tenho, quando ng-change do controller pai for disparado, o método do controller filho for acionado(quando estiver em uso)?

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa para resolver seu problema seria a utilização de sobrecarga.

Ex: Sobrecarga – Número de parâmetros

Mais uma vez vou utilizar o método “apply” do Js para resolver essa questão, como a linguagem mexe muito com prototipos e construtores, nada mais inteligente do que usar esse método de escopo. A idéia que tive foi usar uma função como uma função e ao mesmo tempo como um objeto que segura suas próprias propriedades.

```
var Person = {
Class: function(){  
    //Private
    var name = ''

    //Public
    this.name = function(){
        return this.name[ arguments.length ].apply( this, arguments )
    }

    this.name[0] = function(){ return name }
    this.name[1] = function(n){ name = n }
    this.name[2] = function(a, b){ name = a + " " + b }
    }   
}
```

Aqui eu crio uma função ( método ) com nome “name” e crio mais 3 propriedades dela que são: 0, 1 e 2. São números, mas ainda sim são propriedades do método name. O que a função principal vai fazer é ver quantos parâmetros ela tem e vai chamar a sua propriedade correspondente, que nada mais é que outro método que vai ser executado no mesmo contexto que a name e terá os mesmos parâmetros que a name.

Logo:

```
var Edu  = new Person.Class

Edu .name() //  ''
Edu .name('Eduardo') 
Edu . name() // "Eduardo"
Edu . name('Eduardo', 'Ottaviani')
Edu . name() // "Eduardo Ottaviani"
```

Não é porque eu tive essa idéia não, mas eu considero esta a forma mais elegante de sobrecarga de operadores até agora. Talvez não seja a mais eficiente, não testei sua velocidade em relação as outras técnicas. Se for mais lenta, creio que não seja perceptível.

Fonte.: https://javiani.wordpress.com/2010/04/17/overload-em-javascript/